# Django trailing slash append only on home.html

Tags: python, django, lighttpd

I try to make django not append a trailing slash to my urls

I have set

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

in my settings.py

now there is my urlpatterns :

```
url(r'^foo.html$', 'SensorMonitoring.views.foo'),
url(r'^home.html$', 'SensorMonitoring.views.foo'),
```

I'm running that on a lighttpd server,
when I call 127.0.0.1/foo.html no trailing slash is appended, but when I call 127.0.0.1/home.html it redirects me on 127.0.0.1/home.html/ and I don't want that because the CSS doesn't load if the urd end with a slash

I really don't understand why I have this behaviour only with home.html… I've try with many other urls and they work all

I use django 1.4

Comment: Just a guess, but is the browser cache causing it, rather than the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect`

`url(r'^foo.html$', 'SensorMonitoring.views.foo'),`

`url(r'^foo.html/$', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect('/foo.html')),`